# How to restrict a generic type parameter to child classes?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, parametric-polymorphism

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
    internal class ConcreteLinkedItem : GenericLinkedItem<ConcreteLinkedItem>
    { //Specific methods which use GenericLinkedItem
    }
    internal class GenericLinkedItem<TItem>
        where TItem : GenericLinkedItem<TItem>
    {
        public TItem? Next { get; private set; }
        public TItem? Previous { get; private set; }

        public void AttachNext(TItem item)
        {
            Next = item;
//Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'GenericLinkedItem<TItem>' to 'TItem'...  
            item.Previous = this; 

        }
    }
```

The only solutions I have in mind are:

- Explicit cast (no compile time type check)

```
            item.Previous = (TItem)this;
```

- Abstract method to retrieve this (boilerplate)

```
        public void AttachPrevious(TItem item)
        {
            Previous = item;
            item.Next = GetThis();
        }

        protected abstract TItem GetThis();
```

- Use composition instead of inheritance aka System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList (even more boilerplate).

Any beautiful ideas?

PS: For now I go with "protected abstract TItem This { get; }". Which still is not what I want as you can mix different item (node) types, but is at least type safe:

```
    internal class ConcreteLinkedItem : GenericLinkedItem<ConcreteLinkedItem>
    { //Specific methods which use GenericLinkedItem
        protected override ConcreteLinkedItem This => this;
    }
    internal abstract class GenericLinkedItem<TItem>
        where TItem : GenericLinkedItem<TItem>
    {
        public TItem? Next { get; private set; }
        public TItem? Previous { get; private set; }

        public void AttachPrevious(TItem item)
        {
            Previous = item;
            item.Next = This;
        }

        protected abstract TItem This { get; }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like `ConcreteLinkedItem` is both the item and the list node. Is your composition complaint that the generic linked list has a Value property (I can't remember it's name) and a Next property?

Comment: This is very simplified example. I skip most of the details like Value or any specific implementation in the base class. I come to this when trying to make reactive ordered list, but fall in similar problem when solving other generic solutions.  I named it item so it is not confused with LinkedNode from system generics. Also the host list class which contains First and Last is also not included as it is not directly related to the problem and also it can be completely unnecessary in reactive environment.

Comment: I think your abstract this solution is all you can do really. There is no way for `GenericLinkedItem` to know that it itself is a `TItem` so I think that, forgoing a redesign similar to the existing generic linked list.

Comment: Note that `Nullable<T>` lifted operators also need special-casing